# @odata.context is missing from result when using .NET

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-odata

#### Assemblies affected

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` 8.0.7

#### Expected result

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44323/component-b/odata/$metadata#account",
  "value": [
    {
      "createdOn": "2022-02-15T20:28:58.377Z",
      "accountId": "string",
      "address1Line1": "string",
      "address1City": "string",
      "address1StateOrProvince": "string",
      "address1Country": "string",
      "industryCode": "string",
      "customerSizeCode": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Actual result

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "createdOn": null,
    "accountId": "65465465",
    "address1Line1": null,
    "address1City": null,
    "address1StateOrProvince": null,
    "address1Country": null,
    "industryCode": null,
    "customerSizeCode": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is multiple reasons why this may occur. Solution 1 thru 3 have exactly the same symptoms.

### Solution 1

The controller in the broken component didn't inherit from `ODataController`.

### Solution 2

The route prefix for the endpoint doesn't match the route prefix used in `AddOData(... AddRouteComponents`.

### Solution 3

If you forget the use AddRouteComponents entirely, you'll get the same symptoms.

### Solution 4

Missing a call to `builder.EntitySet<EntityType>(route);` in the EDM model creation.

Symptoms are similar, but only affect the entity that is missing the `EntitySet` call instead of the entire controller.

Comment: One thing I'm trying to figure out is when and where that metadata is added to the response.